# Two-way locator & slider controls

Tags: plotting, manipulate, locator

I was wondering whether it was possible to have a two way control system, whereby one could click and drag both the locator (which would in turn move the sliders), AND click & drag the sliders (which in turn would move the locator). Here is an image of what I would like to achieve:

[image]

The code below controls the locator only:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
Manipulate[n, {n, 1, 20, 1}]
Manipulate[With[{x0 = Clip[p[[1]], {0., 10}]}, 
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImagePadding -> 20, LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Ariel"),
Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red,
Tooltip[Point[#], #] &@{x0, f[x0]}}]], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
AppearanceElements -> None]
```

for which I must credit Michael E2 and Timothy Wofford :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Manipulate` does not remember the previous value of its dynamic variables. So we save their values in another variable. Then whenever the `Manipulate` begins another cycle, we compare the new values to the saved values.

To lock the sliders together we need a function y=f[x] and its inverse x=g[y]. You have to supply both of these relationships; Mathematica will not give you an inverse function.

```
(* Relationships constraining sliders *)
f[x_] := x^2;
g[y_] := Sqrt[y];

(* External variables for remembering previous values *)
xSave = 0;
ySave = 0;
pSave = {0, 0};

Manipulate[
 (* compare values and handle changes appropriately *)
 If[xx != xSave, xSave = xx; p[[1]] = xx; yy = f[xx]];
 If[yy != ySave, ySave = yy; xx = g[yy]];
 If[p != pSave, pSave = p; xx = p[[1]]; yy = f[xx]];

 (* The manipulated object *)
With[{x0 = Clip[p[[1]], {0., 10}]}, 
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Ariel"), 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
    Tooltip[Point[#], #] &@{x0, f[x0]}}]],

 (* The controls *)
 {xx, 0, 10},
 {yy, 0, 100},
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, 
 AppearanceElements -> None]
```

Comment: @ Timothy Wofford, Thank you so much - works brilliantly! :-)

Comment: For the labels, check out [the documentation center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html)