# Draw plot with locator & slider

Tags: plotting, manipulate, locator

I would like to create a plot whereby both the slider and the locator 'draw' the plot. In the following code, the locator & the slider act independently:

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
Manipulate[With[{x0 = Clip[p[[1]], {0, 20}]}, Plot[f[x], {x, 0, t}, 
ImagePadding -> 20, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-2, 2}}, LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> 
"Ariel"), Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Tooltip[Point[#], #] &@{x0, f[x0]}}]], 
{t, 0.001, 20}, {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, AppearanceElements -> None]
```

I would like to get both to work together, so the slider 'draws' the plot, as does the locator when it is dragged. Here is an illustration of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would link one of the controls to the other.  Make one (`t`) update the other (`p`) inside `Dyanmic`.  Make the other update the one inside the body of `Manipulate`.  Then track the other (`p`).  I chose to track `p` because creating a custom slider is easier than creating a custom locator.

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
Manipulate[With[{x0 = Clip[p[[1]], {0.001, 20}]},
  t = x0;
  Plot[f[x], {x, 0, t}, ImagePadding -> 20, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-2, 2}}, 
   LabelStyle -> (FontFamily -> "Ariel"), 
   Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
     Tooltip[Point[#], #] &@{x0, f[x0]}}]],
 {t, 0.001, 20,  Manipulator[Dynamic[t, (p[[1]] = t = #) &], ##2] &},
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None},
 AppearanceElements -> None, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {p}]
```

---

*Update for V10+.*
The control for `t` can now be constructed with [`TrackingFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html):

```
{t, 0.001, 20, TrackingFunction -> ((p[[1]] = t = #) &)}
```

---

How to write custom controls is discussed in [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html#651832353).  Custom controls are declared in a `Manipulate` by pure `Functions`, often used in the form `ctrl[##] &`.  `Manipulate` passes several arguments to the control.  The first argument is `Dynamic[t]`, where `t` is the control's variable.  The second argument is generally a `List` of the data that appears in the variable declaration (e.g. `{0.001, 20}` in the control for `t`). Any other arguments are usually options.  We needed to override just the first argument with a custom `Dynamic`. The rest of the arguments, represented by [`##2`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html), are passed as is.  In this case, one could use `#2` instead of `##2`; one could also explicitly pass `{0.001, 20}` and skip the `#` slots altogether.

The custom `Dynamic` links the slider to the locator:  The locator's x coordinate is reset whenever the slider is moved.  The link from the locator back to `t` is done in the body of the `Manipulate` by `t = x0`.

Finally, the way dynamic updating works can be subtle.  If a symbol `var` is being tracked and the value of `var` is changed in the body of the `Manipulate` during an update, another update will be generated; this causes the body to be executed a again.  (Sometimes this leads to infinite loops.)  If `t` were a tracked symbol, then the `Manipulate` body would execute twice each time the control or locator was moved.  (On the second evaluation, `t` is set to its old value, so a new update is not generated.)  For this reason, I excluded it from being tracked by means of the `TrackedSymbols` option.  The way it is now is that if the `t` slider is moved both `t` and `p` change values; the change in `p` causes an update and the graph is redrawn.  And if `p` changes by clicking on the graph, an update is generated that changes `t` and redraws the graph.

Comment: [(FontFamily -> "Ariel")](http://www.tlc-systems.com/artzen2-0215.htm)

Comment: @belisarius  ["Ariel"](http://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/uranus/voyager2_ariel_catalog_contrast-enhanced.html) looks different on a Mac and on Windows

Comment: @ Belisarius - you are quite right, it should be 'Arial' - silly mistake (although as Michael E2 says, Windows doesn't seem to mind!)

Comment: @ Michael E2, Many thanks - this works perfectly & does exactly what I was after - I am unsure about the implementation of the ## though - in the documentation, it says that ## stands for the sequence of all arguments - but I am not at all clear on what this implies. At the risk of sounding very naive, is this what helps tie the 2 controls to one another?

Comment: @belisarius Hehe, I did not catch the error with font name.  There is an [Ariel](http://www.dafont.com/arielrosejonas.font?text=Ariel).  :)

Answer (score 3):

In your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34403/two-way-locator-slider-controls) we connected the slider to the locator.

Now we change the plot domain: Instead of plotting from 0 all the way to 20 we only plot up to `x0`. We don't want the plotted region to change, so we use the `PlotRange` option (see the [documentation center](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRange.html))

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
(*External variables for remembering previous values*)
xSave = 0;
pSave = {0, 0};
Manipulate[
  (*compare values and handle changes appropriately*)
  If[xx != xSave, xSave = xx; p[[1]] = xx;];
  If[p != pSave, pSave = p; xx = p[[1]];];
  (*The manipulated object*)
  With[{x0 = Clip[p[[1]], {0.01, 20}]}, 
    Plot[f[x],
     (* we only plot up to the locator *)
     {x, 0, x0},
     (* but we display the entire domain *)
     PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-1, 1}}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, 
       Tooltip[Point[#], #] &@{x0, f[x0]}}
  ]],(*The controls*)
  {{xx, 0.01, "x"}, 0.01, 20},
  {{p, {0.01, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}, 
  AppearanceElements -> None]
```

Comment: @ Timothy Wofford, Many thanks for your reply & for building on my previous question - works well (though the position of the number '10' on the x-axis is unstable at beginning & end of plot - is that something to do with x value being 0 rather than 0.001?)

Comment: The `0.01` in my code or `0.001` in Michael's code is because the plot has range `{x,0,x0}` and `x0` cannot be equal to zero. I do not understand what you mean by an unstable position.

Comment: @ Timothy Wofford, It just flickers a bit - no problem though - I see what you mean about the 0.001 :-)

Answer (score 2):

***This a example when I start learning Mathematica.I hope it can help you.Good luck.***

```
Manipulate[
         If[
            ini == pres,
            Graphics[
                    {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{ini, Sin[n ini]}]},
                     Axes -> True,
                     PlotRange -> {{ini, end + 1}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
                     AspectRatio -> Automatic
                    ],
         Plot[
             Sin[n x], {x, ini, pres}, 
             Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[{pres, Sin[n pres]}]}, 
             PlotRange -> {{ini, end + 1}, {-1.2, 1.2}},
             AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.02], 
             AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 18, Purple], Style["y", 18, Purple]}
             ]
          ],
        {{ini, 0, "startvalue"}, 
        ControlType -> InputField}, {{end, 2 Pi, "endvalue"}, 
        ControlType -> InputField}, {{n, 1, "freq"}, 1, 20, 1, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{pres, Pi, "current endvalue"}, ini, end,
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}
    ]
```

> [image]

Comment: @ Tangshutao, Many thanks for your answer - you have added some extra things that I will definitely study :-)

Comment: @martin,Dear martin,Thanks.And I can also learn more from your question.We should learn each other.:-)