# How to restrict the motion of a Manipulate-generated Locator along a line?

Tags: manipulate, locator

If one uses a stand-alone locator and needs it to only be movable along a curve, say, defined by a function `f[x]`, one can use a simple construct:

```
Graphics@Locator[Dynamic[pt, (pt = {#[[1]], f[#[[1]]]}) &]]
```

If one, instead uses a `Manipulate`statement with the `Locator` as a control:

```
Manuipulate[expression,{{pt, {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

where `expression`is some graphics and the initial point {0.5,0.5} lies somewhere inside it, the locator may be moved unrestricted between the points {0, 0} and {1, 1}.

**My question**: how to restrict the motion of the Locator along the line, when using the Locator generated within the Manipulate statement?

To be precise, let it be the line `f[x_]:=x`?

**Comment**: I understand that this may be easily done by means of a slider or alike. I would like, however, to have it controlled by a locator.

**Comment 2**: My question gave rise to a suspect of being a duplicate. Indeed, there were several related questions discussing how to restrict the locator behavior, and solutions are known. The difference is that those solutions always treated the Locators as stand-alone graphics objects. In contrast my question addresses the situation when Locator is fixed as a control in the Manipulate statement. Astonishingly it appears that in this case no solution was so far available.

Comment: [DynamicModule version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46164/5478), do you really insist on Manipulate?

Comment: @Feyre Could you kindly show an example?

Comment: @Kuba, Yes, the locator in question is a part of a large demonstration including a number of different components. It is convenient to keep everything within Manipulate. Apart from that, as it might be clear from my question, I suddenly realized that I know how to do it outside of Manipulate, but have no idea of what to do inside.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Proper exampley now in answer. That is what you meant right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LocatorPane and PlotRange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6031/locatorpane-and-plotrange)

Comment: Some related answers where I used `Dynamic` to constrain `Locator` inside `Manipulate`: [(18090)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18112), [(22134)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22162), [(34701)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34702), [(47221)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47345).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option for a `Manipulate` control, that mimics the functionality of the second argument to `Dynamic` is [`TrackingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrackingFunction.html).

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]

Manipulate[
 Column[{Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]], p}], 
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, TrackingFunction -> (p = {First@#, f@First@#}; &)}]
```

> [image]

---

Using only `Manipulate` and no `Dynamic`

```
f[x_] := Sin[x]

Manipulate[
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], 
  Graphics[{Locator[{First@p, f[First@p]}]}]], 
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

[image: Out]

If the position of the displayed `Locator` is needed in several parts of the code inside `Manipulate`, the following implementation is more convenient

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{locatorPos},
  locatorPos = {First@p, f[First@p]}; 
  Column[{Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True],
      Graphics[{Locator[locatorPos]}]], locatorPos}]], 
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

Two more implementations, that do use `Dynamic` to restrict the `Locator` position to the line given by `f`.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{Show[{Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True],
      Graphics[Locator[Dynamic[p, (p = {First@#, f[First@#]}) &]]]}], p}],
 {{p, {0, 0}}, None}]

Manipulate[
 Column[{Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True]], pPos}],
 {{p, {0, 0}}, {0, Last@pPos}, {2 Pi, Last@pPos}, Locator},
 {{pPos, {Dynamic@First@p, Dynamic@f[First@p]}}, None}]
```

Comment: Thank you, that' s sly. So, you draw a stand-alone locator, (just as I described above), while making the Manipulate one invisible. Smart, thank you.

Comment: It is unfortunately not the intended functionality, since such a locator picks up an wrong coordinate, cf. ` f[x_] := Sin[x];
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True], 
    Graphics[{Locator[{First@p, f[First@p]}]}]],
   p
   }], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}] `

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Please see my edit. You chose the coordinates of the wrong `Locator` to be displayed as a part of your `Column`.

Comment: @ Karsten 7 Should I understand that Manipulate itself contains no such a simple mechanism that would allow that? Is it at least you vision?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I just stumbled upon a `Manipulate` controls option introduced in v. 10.0, that does exactly what you asked for.

Comment: 7 The latter looks, indeed, what I was looking for. I never have met such a possibility. Could you give a hint of where have you seen its mentioning?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I think, [Options & Styling for Interactive Manipulation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OptionsAndStylingForInteractiveManipulation.html) was, where I discovered it.